# How to clear the Dropzone in React Dropzone Component after file upload?

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I need to destroy the dropzone component after file upload, not able to get the dropzone object to apply the dropzone.destroy() method.

Comment: Could you provide some example code of what you've already tried?

Comment: @MattStobbs I finally found an answer to my question I am posting it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the dropzone, we need to get the dropzone object and use the dropzone.destroy() method. We need to first initialize a variable outside the complete component as:

```
var myDropzone;
```

To get the dropzone object we need to use the init event of the dropzone which gives us the dropzone object like below:

```
initCallback (dropzone) {
        myDropzone = dropzone;
        console.log("dropzone"+myDropzone);
    }
const eventHandlers = {
            addedfile: this.onDrop.bind(this),
            removedfile: this.removeFile.bind(this),
            init: this.initCallback.bind(this)
    }
```

Then we can call the dropzone.destroy() method after our upload is completed like this:

```
myDropzone.destroy();
```

It will reset our files array to [] and remove the files from the view also.

Comment: I found an issue with the .destroy method, you cannot use the Dropzone area for again uploading the files, .removeAllFiles method can be used to reuse the dropzone and you also need to clear you files array in your state manually